# Return either xml or json from MVC web api based on request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, wcf-web-api

Given the following webapiconfig;

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and this controller;

```
  public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
         Product[] _products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return _products;
        }
    }
```

Using the URL `http://localhost/api/Products` I get a list of products in XML format.

What I would like to do is have the option to return either json or xml based on the request. So for json, it would be;

```
http://localhost/api/Products.json
```

and for XML, it would be;

```
http://localhost/api/Products.xml
```

likewise;

```
http://localhost/api/Products.json/1/
http://localhost/api/Products.xml/1/
```

Is this possible and how would I achieve this functionality?

An alternative would be something like;

```
http://localhost/api/json/Products/
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that with `AddUriPathExtensionMapping`

You can create routes like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Api UriPathExtension",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{extension}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, extension = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Api UriPathExtension ID",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{extension}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, extension = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you need to extend the formatters:

```
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
  config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
```

MAke sure to add reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting`, as these methods are extension methods and intellisense won't see them by default.

Remember in this example, you still have to issue the request with the appropriate content-type. However, if you want to have these directly available via the browser address bar you can map to "text/html".

I wrote a blog post about all that a while ago - which should be helpful and take you into more details http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/different-mediatypeformatters-for-same-mediaheadervalue-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: The routes seem to work, but the extension stuff doesn't do anything. I added these to global.asax, is this a problem?

Comment: Chris, use {ext} instead of {extension}, because {ext} appears to be hard-coded to refer to the mapped formatter.

Comment: Great thread. Like @MCattle said, Always remember: EXT instead of EXTENSION

Comment: is it possible to achive this with taking another parameter like format=xml or format=json

Comment: how to use this to accept both formats(xml and json) for request?