# C# Web API Either XML or JSON based on GET request

Tags: c#, xml, json, httpresponse, formatter

My config.Routes was set to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this I could use:

- `localhost:port/api/products` - get a full list of products
- `localhost:port/api/products/#` - get a single product with the given id

Based on the browser I was getting a different format (you get XML format in FireFox and Google Chrome as default, and JSON in Internet Explorer).

I mostly need JSON, so at first I added:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

so my response would always be in JSON.

Everything works as intented at this point, and I'm getting JSON-format responses on the two GET-requests mentioned above.

---

I then stumbled on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053485/return-either-xml-or-json-from-mvc-web-api-based-on-request).
Thought it would be a nice feature to select for yourself which format you want to return based on the GET-request.

However, when I replace the config.Routes and JSON-only code mentioned above for:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API UriPathExtentsion",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API UriPathExtension ID",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
```

I'm getting the 404 errors below:

On `localhost:post/api/products`:
[image]

and on `localhost:port/api/products.xml`:
[image]

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Also, I'm not sure the second piece of code will do exactly as I would like to, so here is a list of example requests and what I would like it to return:

- `localhost:port\api\products` - get a list of products in default browser format
- `localhost:port\api\products\#` - get a single product in default browser format
- `localhost:port\api\products.xml` - get a list of products in XML format
- `localhost:port\api\products.json` - get a list of products in JSON format
- `localhost:port\api\products\#.xml` - get a single product in XML format
- `localhost:port\api\products\#.json` - get a single product in JSON format

Thanks in advance for the responses.

---

Edit 1: Changed `exten` to `ext` after a comment. Still the same errors..

Comment: The answer in the post you link to includes [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053485/return-either-xml-or-json-from-mvc-web-api-based-on-request#comment19002795_13053629)... does this help?

Comment: @DaveParsons not really, since I already use `exten` instead of `extension`, as seen in the code of my main-post.

Comment: The comment says to use `{ext}` not `{exten}`.

Comment: @DaveParsons I've changed it to `{ext}` now, but still the same errors..

Comment: Don't you need to keep your original route to get `/api/products` to work?

Comment: Also, from your linked post: **Remember in this example, you still have to issue the request with the appropriate content-type.**  Have you done this?

Comment: @Halvard ok, I missed that.. I'm kinda new to Web APIs though, so where do I add these content-types? I've looked at the link's example project, but he literally added beforeSend ajax functions with hardcoded localhost-links, this obviously isn't what I want. Could you perhaps make a sample post of how I can make a dynamically content-type request header?

Comment: My answer was too long for a comment so I chanced putting it as an answer.  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The post you linked to says:

> Remember in this example, you still have to issue the request with the appropriate content-type.

This means that whoever calls your API need to set the content-type to match either `application/json` or `text/xml`.  If you are calling from a browser your content-type will be the default content-type of the browser you are using, which might easily be `text/plain`.

**Option 1:** Google and find out how to change the content-type of the browser you are using.  I have never tried to change this myself.

**Option 2:** If you call this from code and use C#, use the `HttpClient` and modify the content-type before your call as explained in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request).

**Option 3:** Use the composer in [Fiddler (free)](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to call your service.  There it is easy to set the content-type.  I prefer this when testing web APIs.

When all this is said and done, I'm not sure this actually solves your problem, but I hope so.  At least you then follow everything the post you linked to says.  Good luck!

Comment: +1 - also an option is the Advanced Rest Client for google chrome that allows you to explicitly set all headers, and nicely formats JSON results.