# ASP.NET WebAPI to return XML instead of the default JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, asp.net-web-api

In my WebApiConfig I have

```
  var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

So all the API's come back as JSON.

There is 1 API call that I need to return XML ..

This is what it have now for my return

```
      return XDocument.Load(savedXMLFileFromServer);
```

but it comes back as JSON

Is there anyway to have it come back as XML

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366755/c-sharp-web-api-etiher-xml-or-json-based-on-get-request