# ASP MVC Replace View Generation With JSON At Run Time?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Say I have a controller action like so:

```
public ActionResult Foo() {
    return View(new SomeModel {...});
}
```

Is it possible for me to, at runtime, have this action return **JSON** instead of **HTML**?  This is for some automated testing.  The only way I have found would be to modify my controller's base class to override `View(...)` such that they if some setting is true, it returns `Json(model)` instead of what it normally does.

I'd rather not do that as it would mean a conditional which gets evaluated for every action even in non-test environments.

Comment: `return this.Json(new SomeModel { ... });`

Comment: You can try some like [Return either xml or json from MVC web api based on request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13053485/580951).

Comment: @Nikolay, I only want to get JSON in a test environment -- so that won't work.

Comment: Then return JSON when `#if SOMEFLAG` is true.

Comment: Executing an `if` statement is nothing compared to other operations performed in the method and rendering

Comment: Create `BaseController` with method `ViewOrJson` and in `ViewOrJson` check whether the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` is loaded in the current `AppDomain`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty trivial...

```
public ActionResult Foo() {
    var model = new SomeModel {...};

    if (somePropertyYouWantToCheck)
        return Json(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the MVC feature which does exactly what I want -- filters.  In my case, a global result filter which replaces the ActionResult with a JsonResult.

See http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters

Comment: Obviously I can edit the action itself to return JSON conditionally, but that's not scalable to our entire codebase -- hence global action filters.

Comment: You do realize that action filters don't execute in unit testing, right?