# WebApi: set formatter with custom format string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, formatter

Let's say I have a custom extension `.foo` that implies the expected data type should be a "JSON-esque" document.  For example, let's say I have 2 formatters that can support JSON, the standard JSON.Net and a custom JSON formatter that does kooky things to the JSON document.  I only want to use the second JSON formatter for very specific api calls, and I can change the api endpoint in the client, so I want to do something like this:

```
[Route("~/api/Widgets/{id:int}.{format}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Widget))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(int id)
{
    //stuff goes here
}
```

as such, navigating to

```
https://myserver.com/api/Widgets/1234.foo
```

...should format the response with my "special" formatter for Widget 1234, but

```
https://myserver.com/api/Widgets/1234.json
```

...should return a standard JSON document.

How do I specify that my custom formatter only gets invoked when the `format` identifier is "foo"?  What if I needed to support "foo" and "bar" formats with the same formatter?

I'd like to point out that I am well aware this seems like a silly thing to do, returning an essentially malformed JSON document.  (trying to cut "alternative" or "best practice" answers off at the pass...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question covers exactly what you need:

[Return either xml or json from MVC web api based on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053485)

JSON/XML formatters are used there, however it works in the same way with custom formatters.