# WebAPI mvc 4 set default response type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have following code

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new UriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json"));
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new UriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml"));
```

Now I want if some one does not provide extension in api like `http://apuUrl/getBooks` it should return by default JSON value.

My following scenarios are working fine:

`http://apuUrl/getBooks.json` -> returns JSON

`http://apuUrl/getBooks.xml` -> returns XML

Note: I don't want to make extra routing for every API

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053485/return-either-xml-or-json-from-mvc-web-api-based-on-request

Comment: I saw this... But this require an extra routing for every API

Comment: It can also be achived by setting content-type. Is that an option, or does it has to be in route?

Comment: I see, disregard my first comment.

Comment: What is [tag:mvc-api] and was it really necessary to create a tag for it?

Comment: I have found it common when people saying mvc-api when they really mean to say web api

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx) to override the acceptheader?

```
public class MediaTypeDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var url = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        //TODO: Maybe a more elegant check?
        if (url.EndsWith(".json"))
        {
            // clear the accept and replace it to use JSON.
            request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
        else if (url.EndsWith(".xml"))
        {
            request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And in your configuration:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MediaTypeDelegatingHandler());
```

And your controller:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And if you go to `http://yoursite.com/api/Foo/?.json` should return:

```
"test"
```

While `http://yoursite.com/api/Foo/?.xml` should return

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">test</string>
```

**Edit:**
Note that you still need to handle the route parameter input, since the controller doesn't expect the .json-parameter. That's why the `?` may be necessary.